# how to get success infomation from server when use model 'save method int Extjs

Tags: extjs, model

I have knew the success callback in the store' sync process.
but In my application,I use the model to post  the content to server use the save method.
and i don't knew how to get the success callback that is same as the sync of the store.
thank you .

```
report.data.dm.save({
                                    callback : function() {
                                        Ext.StoreMgr
                                                .lookup('reportListStore_ID')
                                                .reload();
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('result', 'report update success');
                                    }
                                });
```

I use the callback,but I have check that whatever the sever return true or false,the callback will be called.That is'nt What I want to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [callback](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-cfg-callback) takes some arguments. The doc says that it is passed a `success` argument in third position, but that's not implemented in all (if any) versions of Ext4.

So you're better off using the [`operation.wasSuccessful()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation-method-wasSuccessful) method:

```
report.data.dm.save({
    callback : function(record, operation) {
        if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
            // success
        } else {
            // failure
        }
    }
});
```